# What exactly was the reason for Denethor's dislike of Faramir?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, adaptation-comparison, character-motivation

The movies establish that Denethor doesn't really like Faramir, without offering any explanation of motive.

**Are we really given any reason in the books for why Denethor seemed to always favour Boromir over Faramir?**

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/lotr/comments/3lvdpi/why_does_denethor_hate_faramir/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is discussed in Appendix A (emphasis mine):

> Faramir the younger was like [Denethor] in looks but otherwise in mind. He read the hearts of men as shrewdly as his father, but **what he read moved him sooner to pity than to scorn**. He was **gentle in bearing**, and **a lover of lore and of music**, and therefore **by many in those days his courage was judged less than his brother's**. But it was not so, except that he did not seek glory in danger without a purpose. **He welcomed Gandalf at such times as he came to the City, and he learned what he could from his wisdom**; and in this as in many other matters he displeased his father.
>
> <sup>*Return of the King* Appendix A: "Annals of the Kings and Rulers" I "The Númenórean Kings" *(iv) Gondor and the Heirs of Anárion* The Stewards</sup>

It isn't really that Denethor disliked Faramir, it's that he failed to live up to Denethor's standards for manliness, especially when compared to Boromir, so he was always kind of a disappointment. Boromir's death grieved Denethor greatly, and he responded by lashing out at the disappointing son he had left.

In fairness, some of this is covered in the extended edition of the *Return of the King* film:

> **Denethor:** Ever you [Faramir] desire to appear lordly and gracious as a King of old.   Boromir would have remembered his father's need.
>
> *[...]*
>
> **Denethor:** Boromir was loyal to me! Not some wizard's pupil.
>
> <sup>*Return of the King* (2003)</sup>

Comment: There's also the issue that Faramir probably reminded Denethor more of Finduilas, who would appear to have never fully recovered from giving birth to Faramir and died a few years afterward.